# JavaFX SequentialTransition IllegalStateException: Cannot stop when embedded in another animation

Tags: javafx

The test program below reproduces the problem. I understand why the exception is thrown but I would like to know how can I work around it or use a different construct in JavaFX to get what I want.

The full application is a robot simulator with multiple robots that move autonomously, independently, and simultaneously around a field. Each robot has its own SequentialTransition for its particular set of movements. The program adds the SequentialTransitions to a ParallelTransition, which it then plays. Everything was fine until I put in a listener that notices if a robot runs into an obstacle. I've simplified the collision detection in the test program to apply to only one robot and one wall. The point of the error is marked with //** BROKEN!! IllegalStateException on next line.

I really do want to stop the SequentialTransition for a robot that runs into an obstacle but let the other robot(s) continue. How can I do this?

The error comes up in Java 8 but also in Java 11 and JavaFX 15.

```
package sample;

import javafx.animation.ParallelTransition;
import javafx.animation.SequentialTransition;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static final double FIELD_WIDTH = 600;
    private static final double FIELD_HEIGHT = 600;

    private Pane field = new Pane();
    ParallelTransition parallel = new ParallelTransition();
    SequentialTransition sequentialRobot1 = new SequentialTransition();
    SequentialTransition sequentialRobot2 = new SequentialTransition();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

        // Place one field boundary for testing.
        Line northBoundary = new Line(0, 0, FIELD_WIDTH, 0);
        northBoundary.setStrokeWidth(5.0);
        field.getChildren().add(northBoundary);

        // Place the robots on the field.
        // The first robot.
        Rectangle robotBody1 = new Rectangle(100, 300, 60, 60);
        robotBody1.setArcHeight(15);
        robotBody1.setArcWidth(15);
        robotBody1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        robotBody1.setFill(Color.CRIMSON);
        field.getChildren().add(robotBody1);

        robotBody1.boundsInParentProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (northBoundary.getBoundsInParent().intersects(robotBody1.getBoundsInParent())) {
                //** BROKEN!! IllegalStateException on next line
                sequentialRobot1.stop();
                System.out.println("Collision detected");
                parallel.play();
            }
        });

        TranslateTransition translateTransition1 = new TranslateTransition();
        translateTransition1.setNode(robotBody1);
        translateTransition1.setByX(0);
        translateTransition1.setByY(-300);
        translateTransition1.setDuration(Duration.seconds(1));
        translateTransition1.setOnFinished(event -> {
            robotBody1.setLayoutX(robotBody1.getLayoutX() + robotBody1.getTranslateX());
            robotBody1.setLayoutY(robotBody1.getLayoutY() + robotBody1.getTranslateY());
            robotBody1.setTranslateX(0);
            robotBody1.setTranslateY(0);
        });
        sequentialRobot1.getChildren().add(translateTransition1);

        // The second robot.
        Rectangle robotBody2 = new Rectangle(300, 300, 60, 60);
        robotBody2.setArcHeight(15);
        robotBody2.setArcWidth(15);
        robotBody2.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        robotBody2.setFill(Color.CYAN);
        field.getChildren().add(robotBody2);

        TranslateTransition translateTransition2 = new TranslateTransition();
        translateTransition2.setNode(robotBody2);
        translateTransition2.setByX(0);
        translateTransition2.setByY(-100);
        translateTransition2.setDuration(Duration.seconds(1));
        translateTransition2.setOnFinished(event -> {
            robotBody2.setLayoutX(robotBody2.getLayoutX() + robotBody2.getTranslateX());
            robotBody2.setLayoutY(robotBody2.getLayoutY() + robotBody2.getTranslateY());
            robotBody2.setTranslateX(0);
            robotBody2.setTranslateY(0);
        });
        sequentialRobot2.getChildren().add(translateTransition2);

        parallel.getChildren().addAll(sequentialRobot1, sequentialRobot2);
        parallel.play();

        primaryStage.setTitle("Field");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(field, FIELD_WIDTH, FIELD_HEIGHT, Color.GRAY));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are confused about how to implement what you are trying to do. You got `Transitions`, `Sequentials`, and `Parallel` working in a way that does not seem logical.

Comment: It may make more sense to have a single `AnimationTimer` that updates _each_ robot's location per invocation. If a robot is running into an obstacle simply don't move that one robot.

Comment: To make your code [mre] add the fxml file or better define `root` programmatically

Answer (score 0):

@Slaw's idea of using an AnimationTimer is probably the best direction to go, but the obvious answer is to not use the ParallelTransition at all.  Since the robot animations are going to be independent, just use the SequentialTransitions and start them all at the same time by calling play() on each.

Comment: I did as you advised and the test program performed as I wanted. I guess I need to read more about the best use of a ParallelTransitiion.